# jquery, slideToggle and page height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a number of hidden list elements on my page.

I use jquery to show and hide them, using slideToggle().

My html and body height is set to 100%.

When the list elements are shown, you cannot scroll down the page, the page is only the height of the original elements when they were closed up.

How can I get the page height to adjust when the user toggles the lists?

```
<article>
                <div class="sportType box rounded blue shadow textShadow"><img src="/assets/img/site/arrow_white.png" class="arrow icon rotate0"/><img src="/assets/img/site/snooker_icon.png" class="icon"/>Snooker</div>
                <ul id="snooker" class="sportMatches">
                    <li id ="snooker" class="box sub white shadow match">
                        <img src="/assets/img/site/arrow_black.png" class="icon sportMatchArrow rotate0"/>Joe Davis v John Lardner<span class="star starOff"></span>
                        <div class="sportOdds">
                            <ul>
                            <li><span class="oddsLeft">3:1</span><span class="oddsMiddle">Second Half</span><span class="oddsRight">57:21</span></li>
                            <li style="text-align:left;">Match Prices</li>
                            <li><span class=" oddsBox oddsLeft"><span>1</span> 13/5</span><span class="oddsBox oddsMiddle">X 4/5</span><span class="oddsBox oddsRight">2 12/5</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li id ="snooker" class="box sub white shadow match">
                        <img src="/assets/img/site/arrow_black.png" class="icon sportMatchArrow rotate0"/>Peter Lines v Liu Song<span class="star starOff"></span>
                        <div class="sportOdds">
                            <ul>
                            <li><span class="oddsLeft">3:1</span><span class="oddsMiddle">Second Half</span><span class="oddsRight">57:21</span></li>
                            <li style="text-align:left;">Match Prices</li>
                            <li><span class=" oddsBox oddsLeft"><span>1</span> 13/5</span><span class="oddsBox oddsMiddle">X 4/5</span><span class="oddsBox oddsRight">2 12/5</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li id ="snooker" class="box sub white shadow match">
                        <img src="/assets/img/site/arrow_black.png" class="icon sportMatchArrow rotate0"/>Chris Small v Supoj Saenla<span class="star starOff"></span>
                        <div class="sportOdds">
                            <ul>
                            <li><span class="oddsLeft">3:1</span><span class="oddsMiddle">Second Half</span><span class="oddsRight">57:21</span></li>
                            <li style="text-align:left;">Match Prices</li>
                            <li><span class=" oddsBox oddsLeft"><span>1</span> 13/5</span><span class="oddsBox oddsMiddle">X 4/5</span><span class="oddsBox oddsRight">2 12/5</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li id ="snooker" class="box sub white shadow match">
                        <img src="/assets/img/site/arrow_black.png" class="icon sportMatchArrow rotate0"/>Kurt Maflin v Joe Swail<span class="star starOff"></span>
                        <div class="sportOdds">
                            <ul>
                            <li><span class="oddsLeft">3:1</span><span class="oddsMiddle">Second Half</span><span class="oddsRight">57:21</span></li>
                            <li style="text-align:left;">Match Prices</li>
                            <li><span class=" oddsBox oddsLeft"><span>1</span> 13/5</span><span class="oddsBox oddsMiddle">X 4/5</span><span class="oddsBox oddsRight">2 12/5</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </article>



$(".sportType").click(function() {

    $(this).children('.arrow').toggleClass('rotate0').toggleClass('rotate90');
    $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle();

    $(this).toggleClass('rounded').toggleClass('topRounded');

});
```

Comment: I bet showing your code will help...

Comment: If the odds are favorable, I'll take that bet on the grounds that maybe it *won't* help, after all and I'll clean up!

Comment: THe page is still scrollable after is opened (minimize the window) http://jsbin.com/obihep/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: The answer will be in your CSS. Can we see the relevant style declarations?

Comment: all of the containers are set to 100% what else could it be?

Comment: The only reason you wouldn't have a scrollbar on the body when the content gets larger is if you set the overflow to hidden with CSS.